# Uploading Image from local storage to API

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, api, multipartform-data

Suppose I have an api that takes an image and does some processing. Example:

```
@app.post("/upload/")
async def upload_image(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    file_content = await file.read()
    print(file_content)
    extension = file.filename.split(".")[1]
    if extension not in ["png", "jpg"]:
        return {"status": "error", "detail": "File is not supported"}
    ocr_result = ocr(file_content)
    return {"filename": file.filename, "text": ocr_result}
```

And I want to make a post request to this using axios by uploading an image from my local storage. So I did this:

```
let file = fs.createReadStream('discount.jpg')

let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file, 'discount.jpg');
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/', data, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' 
  }  
}).then(function() {
    console.log(response.data);
})
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using an [`fs.ReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-fsreadstream) instance as the `value` argument to [`FormData.prototype.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append). Do you have some reason to believe that Node.js's implementation of `append` accepts `ReadStream` objects? I don't see anything in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#class-formdata) to suggest that. `string` or `Blob`, but not `ReadStream`.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data says Form-Data can recognize and fetch all the required information from common types of streams (fs.readStream, http.response and mikeal's request), for some other types of streams you'd need to provide "file"-related information manually:

Comment: Are you using that, though? Or the `FormData` built into the Node.js API? If you are using that package, you might want to mention that in the question since otherwise others will probably assume it's the Node.js one. :-)